# Как скрыть элемент на странице wordpress для всех кроме админа?

Tags: wordpress

Есть табы на странице. Один из этих табов скрыт вот так:

```
.course-nav-tab-instructor {
    display: none;
}
```

Могу ли я через php или как то по-другому сделать так, чтобы таб был скрыт для всех кроме админа. Если да, то как?

Answer (score 0):

Сделай этот блок по умолчанию display: none

```
if(current_user_can('manage_options') ) { ?>
        <div class="course-nav-tab-instructor" style="display: block"></div> 
    <?php } ?>
```